# Is there a way to use/combine python code with making a google suite add on?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on finding a connector between python code and a google doc add on. I know that .gs is a version of .py. If there is a way to code in python and have the google script understand it, that would be great. Or if that cannot happen, if there is a translator that could work also.

Comment: Google Apps Script (.gs) is based on javascript(.js) **not** python(.py).

Comment: is there a connector from .js to .gs or maybe a guide for the syntax change?

Comment: Because of the comment of @DimuDesigns you should edit your question otherwise you won't probably get the answer you seek.

Comment: @ziganotschka helped me by giving me a good answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can embed the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/python) in your Python code.

This allows you to update the contents of a .gs file from within your Python project and also to create and manage [Add-on deployments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/manage-deployments).

Refer to the [sample](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/python-samples/blob/master/apps_script/quickstart/quickstart.py) of the Python quickstart to learn how to work with Apps Script API.